# Trying to supply format code from another cell

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to use the text function to change the format of numbers in another cell. To do this I use this as an example: 
`=TEXT(100,B5)` where the format code is stored in cell B5. However it does not work. If I then hardcode the format code in the formula eg: 
`=TEXT(100,"0.00")` strangely the result is correct. Why is this?

Comment: Try put '0.00   (with the ' ) in B5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Test]

> If your target format is stored in a cell which has been set to `Text` format, you can use double quotation mark `""` in front and after the cell reference concatenated by the AND sign `&` as shown in the above example to return the value in desired format.